# Database design for 2 tables which are related by an id

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently developing a tool which has the following tables and the respective columns.

```
Budget             Category          Transactions
budget_id          category_id       transaction_id
category_id                          category_id
```

Currently we are mapping the records of Budget to Transactions using category_id.
But we have a glitch in the design. If two budget items have the same category_id, the transactions get mapped to both the budget. How can I have a design which maps the transactions items to the budget items in a one to one fashion but still keeping the loose coupling?

Comment: Based on your later comments you are not looking at a 1 to 1 relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Budget             Category          Transactions
budget_id          category_id       transaction_id
category_id                          budget_id
```

Comment: the issue with that is..what will happen if we add the budget item after we add the transaction item? do we keep the budget_id in Transactions null as default and then update if the clash happens?

Comment: Store transaction after Budget

Comment: we are building a tool where you can add/remove budget items and feed in transactions independently. hence we cant force a flow to add records to these tables. Can we do better if we add another table?

Comment: Does it mean the transaction might have different budgets over the time?

Comment: No. A web form currently just inserts/edits budget items. Another web form inserts/edits transactions. this happens independently. When we summarize, we are trying to map budgeted items to transactions. For eg. a budget has 2 items which belong to the category 'Credit Card'. In scenarios, a user may have 2 or more credit cards. Hence two items in the budget items. Now if he/she pays bills for one of the two credit cards, the transaction is mapped to both of them. This happens since the two items in the budgets and the transaction have the same category 'Credit Card'. this becomes an issue.

Comment: If the transaction can only be tied to one budget That what @RomanNewaza suggests is what you want to do, although it sounds like you wish to maintain the category_id in the Transactions table as well. If you do not have a budget ID at the time of inserting the transaction (which seems weird - where does the money come from?) then you need to leave it null and update the table when appropriate. If a transaction can related to multiple budgets then make another table that is simply budget IDs and transaction IDs to maintain the many-to-many relationship.